# Why is "te" needed in these sentences?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, verbo-pronominal

I was wondering why the pronoun *te* is needed in these sentences:

> **No te preocupes.**
>   (meaning "don't worry")

My confusion here comes from the fact that *preocupar* is already conjugated to *tú* form. Why is it "don't you *you* worry?"

> **¡Que te sientas mejor!**
>   (meaning "feel better")

My confusion here comes from the same thing as above- why the repeat of "you" pronouns?

Comment: Please, check if [this other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4380/12637) answers yours.

Answer (score -1):

As I see the other questions are similar but not quite the same so..

In this case , *te* is used because, in Spanish, the verb **preocupar**
is a transitive verb. Which means that

> **No preocupes.**

wouldn't mean "don't worry" but "don't worry + [somebody or some people]"

> **Don't worry** -> No te preocupes
>
> **Don't worry me** -> No me preocupes
>
> **Dont worry him/her** -> No le/la preocupes